# How do I prove the Euler-Lagrange equations of an isolated system do not depend explicitly on time?

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, symmetry, time

Disclaimer. This is my first question, apologies for any potential standard of the community that I broke or if this question was already asked.

How do I prove the Euler-Lagrange equations of an isolated system are autonomous, i.e., do not depend explicitly on time?
Please note I'm not asking this question for a free particle. I'm assuming an isolated system made of $n$ interacting particles, with $n$ arbitrary.

I saw this statement in the $Energy chapter of the Landau & Lifshitz  vol.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no proof, it is an experimental fact and thus an axiom that can be viewed as part of Galileian invariance:

*All laws of physics for isolated systems  are invariant under time translations when stated by referring to inertial reference frames.*

That is a **fact** you experience everyday in the approximation of Earth as an inertial reference frame. Every experiment (of mechanics in particular) you may make toady can be made tomorrow with the same outcome (up to the obvious time translation).